# How to project fileName when we group with filePrefix in the Mongo aggregation

Tags: java, mongodb

Currently I'm able to group based on filePrefix and getting the record with max fileId.

In the Output, I'm able to get the filePrefix and fileId, but unable to get fileName along with filePrefix and fileId.

Can anyone please help me out regarding this ...

My documents:

```json
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58cbe224238b3953da3bc0bc"),
            "fileName" : "samplefile1_124.txt",
            "filePrefix":"samplefile1",
            "fileId":124
    }
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58cbe257238b3953da3bc0bd"),
            "fileName" : "samplefile2_125.txt",
            "filePrefix":"samplefile2",
            "fileId":125

    }
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58cf8d13f731b796bc343726"),
            "fileName" : "samplefile3_126.dat",
            "filePrefix":"samplefile3",
            "fileId":126
    }
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58cfa525f731b796bc343727"),
            "fileName" : "samplefile1_126.txt",
            "filePrefix":"samplefile1",
            "fileId":126
    }
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58cfa525f731b796bc343728"),
            "fileName" : "samplefile2_127.txt",
            "filePrefix":"samplefile2",
            "fileId":127

    }
```

My code:

```java
    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
    MongoDatabase db = mongo.getDatabase("fileDB");
    MongoCollection<Document> col =  db.getCollection("fileStatus");

    List<String> docsList = new ArrayList<>();
    docsList.add("samplefile1");
    docsList.add("samplefile2");
    docsList.add("samplefile3");

    Set<String> docsSet = new HashSet<>();
    for(String st: docsList){
        docsSet.add(st);
        }

    Document match =  new Document("$match", new Document("filePrefix",new Document("$in",docsSet)));
    Document group =  new Document("$group" , new Document("_id","$filePrefix").append("fId", new Document("$max","$fileId")));
    Document project = new Document("$project",new Document("filePrefix","$_id").append("fileId", "$fId"));

     AggregateIterable<Document> output = col.aggregate(Arrays.asList(match,group,project));

        for (Document dbObject : output)
        {
            System.out.println(dbObject);
        }
```

My output:

> Document{{_id=samplefile1, filePrefix=samplefile1, fileId=126.0}}
>   Document{{_id=samplefile2, filePrefix=samplefile2, fileId=127.0}}
>   Document{{_id=samplefile3, filePrefix=samplefile3, fileId=126.0}}

Comment: Use `$first` or `$last` with file name in group stage. Something like `.append("fileName", new Document("$first","$fileName")`. Use sort stage before group if you want to control the order.

Comment: I do not want the first fileName. I need the max fileId's fileName to be diplayed in the output

Comment: As @Veeram suggests, if you `$sort` ascending by `fileId` as a second pipeline step and then use `$last` in your `$group` step to get the `fileName`, you'll have the filename associated with the maximum fileId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to run the following aggregate pipeline which sorts the documents first before applying the group operation as you need to use the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** (if in descending order) or **[`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last)** (if in ascending) operator should you wish to return other fields. This in essence will give you the max field as well as the corresponding document fields.

For example using the sample documents as the input

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "filePrefix": { "$in": docsSet }  } },
    { "$sort": { "filePrefix": 1, "fileId": -1 } },
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$filePrefix",
            "fileId": { "$first": "$fileId"},
            "fileName": { "$first": "$fileName"}
        }
    }
])
```

i.e. translated as

```
Document match =  new Document(
    "$match", new Document("filePrefix",
        new Document("$in", docsSet)
    )
);
Document sort =  new Document("$sort", 
    new Document("filePrefix", 1).append("fileId", -1)
);
Document group =  new Document("$group" , 
    new Document("_id", "$filePrefix")
        .append("fileId",  new Document("$first", "$fileId")
        .append("fileName",  new Document("$first", "$fileName")
    )
);
Document project = new Document("$project",
    new Document("filePrefix", "$_id")
        .append("fileId", 1)
        .append("fileName", 1)
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped me.